# Creating/updating NamedCredential from Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api, namedcredentials

## Question

Is it possible to create or update a `NamedCredential` from within `Apex`?

**Investigation**

I looked into available options, and it seems the **[`SOAP API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_namedcredential.htm)** only supports the `describeSObjects()`, `query()`, and `retrieve()` operations. The **[`Tooling API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm)** doesn't seem to support the object at all. But the **[`Metadata API`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_namedcredential.htm)** does!

Let's play around with some scripts in `Execute Anonymous` and see what we can do with the [`Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

## Working with the Metadata API

**Helper Methods**

Here are some bare-bones helper methods pulled out of the [`MetadataServiceExamples`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) class:

```
static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
    return service;
}
static List<MetadataService.SaveResult> createMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata input)
{
    return createService().createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { input });
}
static List<MetadataService.SaveResult> updateMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata input)
{
    return createService().updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { input });
}
static List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> deleteMetadata(String type, String fullName)
{
    return createService().deleteMetadata(type, new List<String> { fullName });
}
```

### NamedCredential

I tried to run a `NamedCredential` through these methods and was not able to get `createMetadata` or `updateMetadata` to work. The errors are included below. To my surprise, however, `deleteMetadata` runs successfully if the other methods are left out. I don't see any mention in the documentation of which operations are supported...

**Script**

```
MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credential';
credential.label = 'Demo Credential';
credential.endpoint = 'https://www.DEMO2.com';

system.debug(createMetadata(credential));
system.debug(updateMetadata(credential));
system.debug(deleteMetadata('NamedCredential', credential.fullName));
```

**Error on `createMetadata`**

> Line: 11534, Column: 1
>   System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not a valid value for the enum 'ExternalPrincipalType' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=

**Error on `updateMetadata`**

> Line: 11364, Column: 1
>   System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not a valid value for the enum 'ExternalPrincipalType' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=

### ApexPage

Just to make sure my installation works correctly, I slightly tweaked some examples from the [`MetadataServiceExamples`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) class. The `createMetadata()`, `updateMetadata()`, and `deleteMetadata()` calls each work fine for the `ApexPage` type.

**Script**

```
MetadataService.ApexPage apexPage = new MetadataService.ApexPage();
apexPage.apiVersion = 25;
apexPage.fullName = 'test';
apexPage.label = 'Test Page';
apexPage.content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('<apex:page/>'));

system.debug(createMetadata(apexPage));
system.debug(updateMetadata(apexPage));
system.debug(deleteMetadata('ApexPage', apexPage.fullName));
```

**Abbreviated Logs**

> (SaveResult:[errors=null, fullName=test, success=true])
>   (SaveResult:[errors=null, fullName=test, success=true])
>   (DeleteResult:[errors=null, fullName=test, success=true])

Comment: On the docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_namedcredential.htm there's a ExternalPrincipalType enum. Maybe you need to put a value while setting up the named credential?

Comment: You'll probably need a protocol as well

Comment: @FernandoGavinho Interesting, I searched for it in the documentation but didn't see it for some reason.

Comment: @FernandoGavinho Right on both counts. If you can whip up an answer that verifies as much I will accept it. Not sure if you have the package installed anywhere... If it's too much work I can also answer it myself.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson did you install whole mdapi wrapper package from financialforce or you extracted only some piece of code those were necessary ?

Comment: I don't remember all that well, it was 4 years ago. I think I may have just copied in the service I needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add two required "fields" to your request: `principalType` and `protocol` (you can see the entire list of fields [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_namedcredential.htm))

**Script**

```
MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credential';
credential.label = 'Demo Credential';
credential.endpoint = 'https://www.DEMO2.com';
credential.principalType = 'NamedUser';
credential.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';

system.debug(createMetadata(credential));
system.debug(updateMetadata(credential));
```

**Abbreviated logs**

> (SaveResult:[errors=null, fullName=Demo_Credential, success=true)
>   (SaveResult:[errors=null, fullName=Demo_Credential, success=true)

Comment: How does one import `MetadataService.NamedCredential` ? I get a failure that the class does not exist.

Comment: Install this: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Answer (score 2):

On v59.0, Salesforce has added some nice methods to work with Named Credentials / External Credentials without the need of installing `apex-mdapi`.

You can find some usage examples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/named-credentials/guide/nc-create-oauth-cred.html), and the documentation of the Apex class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods).

The caveat is that you can create both Named and External credentials, but only update External credentials.