# Updating NamedCredential through Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api

**Question**

Is it possible to update or create NamedCredential from Apex ?

**some background from internet search**

From my investigation found that it's possible to update `NamedCredential` through MetdataAPi and then
Found this [Possible to update NamedCredential from Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165551/possible-to-update-namedcredential-from-apex) , a time saver :).

However, after successful installation of [apex-mdt](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) ,i have added new apex class to create/update Namedcredential (this class will internally MetadataService Class).

when i tried to call my newly created apex class(MetadataWrapper), i was getting an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature"

Issue Raised at : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/231

Not sure what is missing, Please Help!

**EDIT 1:**

I was using wrong logic for createService() and createMetadata(). clear steps mention in answer.

Comment: Actually method "createMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata[] metadata)"  takes an array as parameter   and you are just passing an instance of MetadataService.Metadata

Comment: I tried using createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { input }) this as well

Comment: Please add your error message *verbatim* and also your code. Without either of these things, your question is off topic.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sorry for inconvenience,able to resolve it with knowledge from your question. Did you try implementing this using Tooling API as well ?

Comment: No inconvenience, your question as posted is just not answerable by anyone but yourself. No I never did.

Comment: I will remove my downvote if you include the relevant code in your question and actually mention the error message verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using wrong function signature for createService() , hence issue.

STEP1: Deploy https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

STEP2:
**Create New Class after deploying apex-mdt: [Code From](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165551/possible-to-update-namedcredential-from-apex)**

```
public class MetadataWrapper {
    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
    {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;
    }
    public static List<MetadataService.SaveResult> createMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata input)
    {
    return createService().createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { input });
    }
    public static List<MetadataService.SaveResult> updateMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata input)
    {
    return createService().updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { input });
    }
public static List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> deleteMetadata(String type, String fullName)
    {
    return createService().deleteMetadata(type, new List<String> { fullName });
    }
}
```

STEP 3:  **Example Call from Anonymous:**

```
    MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
    credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credentia';
    credential.label = 'Demo Crential';
    credential.endpoint = 'https://www.DMO2.c';
    credential.principalType = 'NamedUser';
    credential.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
system.debug(MetadataWrapper.createMetadata(credential));
    system.debug(MetadataWrapper.updateMetadata(credential));
```

Comment: Please include the relevant snippet of code to show how this is used. See [ask] and [answer].

Comment: @DaveHumm Updated answer. Sorry for inconvenience.